# Complex Cosmological constant

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, complex-numbers, cosmological-constant

Does a complex cosmological constant ($\Lambda = a + ib,\quad b\neq 0$)  exist? If it does exist, what does it represent physically?
For example, we interpret $\Lambda > 0$ as dS space and $\Lambda < 0$ as AdS. These have different cosmological consequences. Hence I am wondering about complex constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cosmological constant enters the Einstein equations in the $\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$ term. Classically, the Einstein equations result from differential geometry, where all objects of interest are real-valued, since by definition all charts of a differentiable manifold have values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (corresponding tuples of real coordinates).

When trying to make the Einstein equations quantum, some of the objects like the metric tensor are thought as operators acting on a complex Hilbert space. But since the operators represent observables, they are required to be hermitian, which just reflects the fact that physical measurements always give real results (eigenvalues of the operators). But with a complex $\Lambda$ the operator $\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$ would be antihermitian and thus not an observable any more which sounds pretty unphysical to me.